# $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$ Cartan subalgebra

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, lie-algebra

For the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n)$, $n^2$ $n \times n$ real and antisymmetric matrices can be introduced as

$$(M_{pq})_{jk} = \delta_{pj}\delta_{qk}-\delta_{pk}\delta_{qj}, \qquad j,k=1, ..., n $$

with

$$ [M_{pq},M_{rs}]=\delta_{qr}M_{ps}-\delta_{qs}M_{pr}- \delta_{pr}M_{qs} + \delta_{ps}M_{qr},$$

and a basis of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ is given by the matrices $M_{pq}$, with $p<q=1, ..., n$.

In the case of the $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1),\, l=1,\,2,...$, how can I construct a basis of the Cartan subalgebra?

I know that a Cartan subalgebra is a maximal abelian subalgebra of the considered Lie algebra, but I don't really understand how to generically find a Cartan subalgebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in right part of generator commutator you have zero, if all indices in left part is not equal. So you can construct Abelian subalgebra as 
$$
M_{12},\; M_{3,4}, \dots, M_{2n-3, 2n-2}, M_{2n-1,2n}
$$

It is maximal commutative subalgebra. Dimension is equal $[\frac{2n+1}{2}]=n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, how can I be convinced that it is maximal?

Comment: Any subalgebra with dimension $n+1$ is not abelian.

Comment: You can try to understand it with simple example of $so(3)$

Comment: $n+1$ in the case of $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$? I don't really understand this, sorry.

Comment: Yes, this algebra can not be commutative

Comment: Could you please point out to a reference discussing the maximal dimension of commutative subalgebras? This would be much appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: I recommend 6.2 from Zee book on group theory https://emineter.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/a-zee-group-theory-in-a-nutshell-for-physicists-2016-princeton-university-press.pdf

Comment: See also http://www.astro.sunysb.edu/steinkirch/books/group.pdf

Comment: Cartan subalgebra is more than just a maximal abelian subalgebra, you need to check its elements $x$ are such that $\text{ad}(x)$ is diagonalizable. How would you check this for the elements $M_{12},M_{34},...$?